# Wamp php extension loaded but not showing under PHP Extensions

Tags: php, apache, wamp, wampserver

When you install WAMP, it gives you a homepage with some details including which extensions are installed. On that list, my installation of memcache shows up. But when I go to WAMP Tray Icon > PHP > PHP Extensions, it does not show up.

Any idea why, should I be concerned about this? It's on 64bit windows if that makes a difference, because I know there are special versions of memcache for x86/64.

Comment: What version of WAMPServer are you running?

Comment: 3.0.6 64bit is the version under About

Comment: Dont worry about it. Memcached has been superceeded by Opcache anyway, and you also need to install the Memcached server to get memcached working anyway

Comment: Right, I have the memcached server installed and running and everything is operating as expected, but it simply isn't showing up like I said.